# Excel validation list allowing invalid inputs

Tags: vba, dropdownbox

I have a worksheet with several different validation lists using named ranges on a different sheet.  I realized that the cells using the ranges with blanks in them still allow the user to type in whatever they want.  If there's no blank in that defined range, then the normal Excel error message pops up.  Anyone know why this happens?

Ex:[image]

Both types of validation lists are the default settings with "Ignore blank", "In-cell dropdown", and the Error Alert checked.

Some of my lists have spaces in between them but I would still like to restrict users to selecting only the choices provided by the dropdown.

Update:

I tried unchecking the "Ignore Blanks", but one minor issue this causes is that now the user can't press "Backspace" to clear the cell.  They have to actually select one of the blank rows in the drop down list.

I discovered another issue which may only be specific to my code (not the example):

-if the cell already has an option selected

-the user tries to delete the cell via "Backspace" and the Excel error message pops up

-if I click Retry and click on the drop down list again, I get 3 of these:

[image: Error 50290]

-the error is from the Worksheet_Change sub and occurs despite me having an error handler within it

Comment: Just found out this same bug the hard way... A blank cell in a Data Validation List will make the whole validation useless/non-blocking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to uncheck the option for `Ignore blank` in the data validation dialog box.

Then Excel will give an error message when the user tries to enter data even if there are empty cells in the named range used by the data validation.

[image]

Comment: @KingKong The `Application or object defined error` that you get depends on the code. This may be part of a different problem. Please test this issue isolated on a separate spreadsheet

Comment: When you have the data validation settings as shown in the answer above, users are allowed to press delete to clear the cell

Comment: See sample workbook here http://expirebox.com/download/010875105c5239764e9d00b8a619be4c.html

Comment: You're right, I meant "Backspace".  I guess those 2 are not equivalent?

Comment: They are not. Pressing backspace causes the cell to go to edit mode and then pressing enter would cause the data validation to trigger. If a cell which has data validation enabled like this, then the delete key needs to be used to clear the cell. Or if you want to use the backspace, then you need to have a blank cell in the list as well